# Running dockerized Zookeeper on Mac M2 gives the error: "The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform..."

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apple-silicon

I've seen similar questions like the one I'm asking but none of the solutions appear to solve my problem.

I have an MacBook M2 Max and I'm trying to run a Kafka docker compose file I currently use on my Windows machine.

Whenever the image for Zookeeper is downloaded, I get a warning saying, "The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8)".

Following a couple of answers I got off here, I added platform: linux/amd64 to my docker compose file, but I'm still getting the warning.

Here's my docker compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    platform: linux/amd64
    restart: always
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    networks:
      - app-mysql
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    platform: linux/amd64
    container_name: kafka
    hostname: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    networks:
      - app-mysql
  redis:
    image: bitnami/redis:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    hostname: redis
    container_name: redis
    environment:
      ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
      REDIS_DISABLE_COMMANDS: FLUSHDB,FLUSHALL
    volumes:
      - "redis_data:/bitnami/redis/data"
    networks:
      - app-mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    hostname: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "Password@1"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "tgipay_merchant_auth"
      MYSQL_USER: "user1"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "Password@1"
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - mysql_config:/etc/mysql/conf.d
    networks:
      - app-mysql
volumes:
  mysql_data:
  mysql_config:
  redis_data:
    driver: local
networks:
  app-mysql:
    driver: bridge
```

Please, what could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there an `linux/arm64` platform image available for the containers you're using?  That error will remain as long as you're using Docker images that target a different architecture than your M2's host architecture (aarch64 or linux/arm64 iirc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, wurstmeister doesn't have a zookeeper imagine for arm. So I switched to bitnami:

```
zookeeper:
    # image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    image: docker.io/bitnami/zookeeper:3.8
    restart: always
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: yes
    networks:
      - app-mysql
  kafka:
    # image: wurstmeister/kafka
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3.4
    container_name: kafka
    hostname: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      # KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: yes
    networks:
      - app-mysql
```

I'm no longer having the issue anymore.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because the lack of some images built for Arm64 is not available, one solution to this problem is to use the experimental feature called Rosetta. Upgrade Docker and then check the Rosetta experimental feature then you can use buildx to make build for the platform of the image you are using (for example: amd64).

- upgrade Docker
- activate experimental feature **Rosetta**
- build for target platform that is based on amd64 (or ready) binary
- build and run with the "**--platform=linux/arm64**" option;

  docker buildx build --platform=linux/arm64 .